# How to test container to tell me it knows how many items it holds

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This component generates an unordered list with 5 li. I simply want to write a test that says this container knows how many li are sitting inside it. I am literally using the same code listed on Enzyme docs BUT instead of getting the desired output I'm getting an empty object {}. What am I doing wrong? Note: I also have Jest installed so ...that also seems to be confusing me.
(I am expecting "Expected" and "Received" to come back as 5)

test output

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected: 5
    Received: {}
```

component code

```
import React from "react"
import TabLink from "./TabLink";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";
import Nav from "./Nav";

export default function TabLinkContainer({selectedId, items, handleClick}) {

    const tabLinks = items.map(({id, label, isDisabled}) => (
        <ErrorBoundary key={id}>
            {/*{console.log("inside TabLinkContainer: ", selectedId, ",", id)}*/}
            <TabLink
                id={id}
                handleClick={handleClick}
                isDisabled={isDisabled}
                isSelected={selectedId === id}
                text={ typeof label === 'object' ? label.text : label}
                icon={label.icon || null}
            />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    ));
    return <Nav tabs className="scroll">{tabLinks}</Nav>;
}
```

test file

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import TabLinkContainer from '../Tabs/TabLinkContainer';
import TabData from '../Tabs/TabsData';
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

let activeTab = '0';
let post = TabData;

describe('TabLinkContainer', () => {
    const handleClick = (tab,event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (active !== tab) {
            this.setState({ active: tab })
        }
    };

    it('knows number of tabs it contains', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
           <TabLinkContainer
               selectedId={active}
               handleClick={handleClick}
               items={post}
           />
           );
        expect(wrapper.find('ul').children()).toEqual(5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare the *children* of the `ul` element with a number.

What you are looking for would be the *count* of children:

```
expect(wrapper.find('ul').children().length).toEqual(5);
```

OR use `expect`s built in `toHaveLength` method:

```
expect(wrapper.find('ul').children()).toHaveLength(5);
```